# how to define that a point in out of a zone in google map

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, gwt

I want to write a class that defines a geographical point is in a zone or out of it;
I save the point in  sequence that they connected to each other when create zone ;
no how can i determine that a point is in zone or out of zone ;

this picture depicts the mentioned zone

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Would have been better to post it in algorithm ... What behavior do you expect if there is a hole in your zone ? Is it considered inside ? Do you have any constraints about the general size ? Do you want it to be fast or to be 100% sure ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon ; https://github.com/maxogden/geojson-js-utils; EDIT: even better, https://github.com/isterin/geo-utils (works on lat/lon)

Comment: Draw a horizontal (or vertical) line trough the point and check if it crosses an even or odd number of your zone outline sections. EDIT look at @Amadan's links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the most simple solution is to use a RayCaster.

Simply choose a random direction (basically horizontally or vertically), and draw a line following it from your point. Count how many times it cross a limit : inside if odd, outside if even.

Ref : [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is Geofencing. Here's a tutorial that might help:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps